# QGIS 3.4 - Print composer export to image error

Tags: qgis, print-composer, qgis-print-layouts

In QGIS 3.4.4.1 when exporting Print composer layout to image (.png, .jpeg) I get the following error message:
"Cannot write to C:\xxxxx.png. This file may be open in another application".
This file does not yet exist so is not open in another application. Exporting to .pdf and .svg works but export to image doesn't. Any ideas?

Comment: do you have permission to create files in c:\?

Comment: Yep - running in admin profile

Comment: Do you have an older version of QGIS installed? If so, try exporting the same layout to the same location. That should tell you if it's a bug with the new QGIS version.

Comment: I'd add a folder (c:\foldername\xxxx.png) or, just write to temp (c:\temp\xxxx.png). It may seem like you have permissions but root on c drive can be tricky.

Comment: @csk Yes previous versions of QGIS work fine

Comment: @enolan sorry I should have been clearer - I'm trying to save to c:\folder\subfolder1\subfolder2\subfolder3\xxx.png

Comment: it doesn't sound like you're doing anything wrong, so it's most likely a bug in QGIS. You can make a bug report here: https://issues.qgis.org

Answer (score 4):

The fix would be to *not* include a period `.` in the output file name.  I have verified this in `QGIS version 3.6.2-Noosa`

Example, if your print composer layout is named `Atlas test-8.5x11`, when you output a raster, then be sure to name the output file without any extra `.`, e.g., `Atlas test-85x11.tif`.

For vector output, such as PDF or SVG, you do not have to do anything different, as it will work as expected.

This QGIS issue, https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/26308, titled ***Error exporting layout with "." (full stop) in filename*** mentions the error code

> "Cannot write to `<FILE_LOCATION>`. This file may be open in another application." The file is not open in another application.

---

[image]